# Opening up your MacBook and how to avoid static electricity

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, repair

Static electricity can exert incredibly high voltages (upward of a thousand volts) which can zap sensitive equipment. Hence, all videos that explain opening up your Mac feature some form of exhortation to first touch the heater or something. But how do you actually keep statics to a minimum?

Do you have to touch the heather/an earthed part every two minutes, every three?

Also, I have seen here http://hardforum.com/archive/index.php/t-1256310.html that it may be a good idea for UK folks to switch off the wall jack but leave the cord plugged in to take advantage of the earthing. Would that avoid all static electricity?

Also, how about a wooden desk? Is that an appropriate surface to conduct MacBook surgery?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run around naked there is no static build up.

But that is not always a option.

So it is the clothes that charge up.

Some clothing materials are worse than others.

Siting on a chair with wheels is not good, but then you can have a static discharge mat under it.

Dry air amplifies the problem of static charge

The key is your shoes, or no shoes. That is one place where you can get discharged, leather soles on a concrete (tiles) ground, and no rubber soles on wooden floor

In a professional environment the people where a arm bracelet that is connected to a ground. That is not always applicable for home and walking around.

You can get one of this products http://www.amazon.com/b?node=1069150